# Performance Logs and Alerts Service will not start

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, logging

I have a Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 machine that recently shutdown due to a power cut, after rebooting the Performance Logs and Alerts Service will not start.

When I try to restart the service is stops automatically with a message that it has no work to do.

Also in my event log I have the following error message

> The performance strings in the Performance registry value is corrupted when process Performance extension counter provider. BaseIndex value from Performance registry is the first DWORD in Data section, LastCounter value is the second DWORD in Data section, and LastHelp value is the third DWORD in Data section.

Any ideas how to fix this corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search revealed the following

http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/4845

and running the command

C:\WINDOWS\system32> lodctr /R

fixed my problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should have performed that search before posting the question.